# Gulp JavaScript file filtering without their parent folders

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bower

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826200/gulp-src-include-files-but-ignore-all-folders), this package [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) and something about globs [here](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpsrcglobs-options), I cannot find the way to make the following code snippet to filter only the JavaScript files without their parent folders:

```
gulp.task("distribution", function () {

    return gulp.src("distribution/**/*.js", { nodir: true })

    .pipe(gulp.dest("www/javascripts"));

});
```

What I get is the following file structure:

```
javascripts/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

javascripts/hammerjs/hammer.js

javascripts/jquery/dist/jquery.js

javascripts/localforage/dist/localforage.js

javascripts/moment/moment.js

javascripts/vue/dist/vue.js

javascripts/vue-touch/vue-touch.js
```

And what I want to get is the following file structure:

```
javascripts/bootstrap.js

javascripts/hammer.js

javascripts/jquery.js

javascripts/localforage.js

javascripts/moment.js

javascripts/vue.js

javascripts/vue-touch.js
```

I've also try this code snippet with no result at all:

```
gulp.task("distribution", function () {

    const filterToApply = filter("*.js", { restore: true });

    return gulp.src("distribution/**")

    .pipe(filterToApply)

    .pipe(gulp.dest("www/javascripts"));

});
```

While this one give me the same result as the first one:

```
gulp.task("distribution", function () {

    const filterToApply = filter("**/*.js", { restore: true });

    return gulp.src("distribution/**")

    .pipe(filterToApply)

    .pipe(gulp.dest("www/javascripts"));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pipe that filter with [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) by adding:

`.pipe(flatten())` right before the gulp.dest pipe.

for example:

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.src('distribution/**/*.js')
  .pipe(flatten())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('"www/javascripts'));
```